# Order by multiple meta key and meta value

Tags: wp-query, metabox

How can I set multiple meta keys order by meta value, can any one give me some example?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE - for us to help you, you need to help us. Can you describe in more detail what you are trying to do, and perhaps post some code samples.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed or requested more info, this is very straightforward clear and with right tags...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`meta_query` is an array of meta clauses. For example:

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'state',
            'value' => 'Wisconsin',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'city',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ), 
    ),
) );
```

You can use an associative array, with a key for each meta clause:

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'state_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'state',
            'value' => 'Wisconsin',
        ),
        'city_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'city',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ), 
    ),
) );
```

Then, you can use that keys in the `order_by` argument, with one:

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'state_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'state',
            'value' => 'Wisconsin',
        ),
        'city_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'city',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ), 
    ),
    'orderby' => 'city_clause', // Results will be ordered by 'city' meta values.
) );
```

Or more clauses:

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'state_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'state',
            'value' => 'Wisconsin',
        ),
        'city_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'city',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ), 
    ),
    'orderby' => array( 
        'city_clause' => 'ASC',
        'state_clause' => 'DESC',
    ),
) );
```

Example taken from [this post](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/) in Make WordPres Core blog.

Comment: do not forget to add the type of the meta key/value. it will affect the results. by default wp will treat your meta as a string.

Comment: But what if I don't want to only return results where the state is Wisconsin? I want all states to be returned and and I want rows where there may or may not be a city and still order by those 2 fields. e.g. no WHERE clause at all - just an ORDER BY.

Comment: Felix, with those requirements a workaround might be to include a final 'catch all' in your meta_query, and put it last in your orderby statement. So the first few clauses in your meta_query would get the specific results you want to order by first. Then your last clause would be everything that is *not* your previous clauses.

Comment: `EXISTS` is a nice way how get the *complex named meta query* but at the same time *not* filter by the value :) 
Btw: I had a real life use case - request was to **order events by date DESC but time ASC using 1 single date&time field** I used docs & this answer to build this: https://ideone.com/RUoyZs :-)

Comment: Wow this is very interesting