# Sort in WP_Query(), not filter? Is it possible?

Tags: wp-query, sort

I want to query and SORT in WP_Query(). But whatever I do, it only prints posts with meta_key set up. But I want all the results and just sort them.

This is my query:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'DESC'
));
```

Any ideas how to make sorting happen? It sorts, but only shows posts with meta_key set up. I want all the posts.

Comment: You'll need to hook into the [`posts_orderby`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby) filter for that.

Comment: Ok so as I understand correctly. I now have custom posts in wp_posts table and custom meta in wp_postmeta. Now I only need a way to "connect" those two. So in return it should be something like wp_posts.wp_postmeta DESC? Or how do I connect those two tables? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to sort the posts by the meta `post_views_count`, and still include posts that *do not* have that meta, you can use [`meta_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) like so:

```php
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR', // make sure it's OR
    // Include posts that have the meta.
    array(
        'key' => 'post_views_count',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    ),
    // Include posts that don't have the meta.
    array(
        'key' => 'post_views_count',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
    ),
),
```

And you can just use that in place of this:

```
'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
```

I.e. Your code would look like:

```php
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'      => 'my_post_type',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'post_views_count',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'post_views_count',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried `'meta_query'`? See [Order by multiple meta key and meta value [closed]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/246358/30597). In your case maybe like so:

```
$query = new WP_Query([
  'post_type'      => 'my_post_type',
  'post_status'    => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'meta_query'     => [
    'relation'         => 'OR',
    'post_views_count' => [
      'key'     => 'post_views_count',
      'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    ],
  ],
  'orderby'        => [
    'post_views_count' => 'DESC',
    'title'            => 'ASC',
  ],
]);
```