# Order (by ASC) posts with meta_key so posts without values are last

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, sort, meta-value

I am trying to figure out sorting posts with prices in one meta query, so the posts without prices are shown last, when ordered by ASC and not first.

Right now I am temporarily not showing posts without prices but it can't be left like that.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'inwestycja',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'meta_key'      => 'price',
        'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC',
        'orderby'      => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_value' => 1,
        'meta_compare' => '>',
        'order'        => 'ASC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'inwestycje',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $tax->term_id,
            )
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => 24,
        'paged' => $paged,
    );
```

Any suggestion how to approach such a problem, without extra work on front end. Extra switches for empty posts with empty prices and so on. Automatic solution :)

Problem is that ASC sorts posts with no price as cheapest, so they are first :)

Comment: I think you should probably just remove all the `meta_` args like `meta_key`, and then use the `meta_query` arg instead. See my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/333794) and try to implement the solution in your code.

Comment: Christine Cooper, why have you deleted my follow up to my own question ? This is the code that helped me sort out my original problem