# Creating a query that get all posts but places meta items first

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I have a query that gets jobs based on a category. Some of these jobs are "featured" issue is the old system used a "featured" meta key, the new system uses "job_featured" meta key (both have 1 for true). I need place the the posts with a true meta value ahead of all posts all order by date so this:

```
post
post
featured
post
job_featured
```

would output as:

```
featured
job_featured
post
post
post
```

I have this to build my query:

```
      $jobs = array( 
        'post_type' => 'job', 
        'tax_query' => array( array (
          'taxonomy' => 'jcategory',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => $category
        )),
        'order' => 'DSC',
        'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
        'paged' => $paged,
      );
...
      $jobs['meta_query'] = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
          'key' => 'job_featured',
          'value' => 1
        ),
        array(
          'key' => 'featured',
          'value' => 1
        ),
        array(
          'key' => 'job_featured',
          'value' => 0,
        ),
        array(
          'key' => 'featured',
          'value' => 0,
        )
      );

      $jobs['orderby'] = array(
        'date' => 'DESC',
        'job_featured' => 'DESC',
        'featured' => 'DESC'
      );
$jobs = (object)$jobs;
$jobSearch = new WP_Query($jobs);
```

the `'value' => 0` is to get all non-featured jobs.

This sorts by date no issue but the feature and job_featured posts are mixed into the results.

Am I missing anything to get this to sort as expected (sort by date then by featured/job_featured)?

Comment: This might help as it explains how to sort multiple meta query clauses: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/246358/45202

Comment: @jdm2112 Either way, it only sorts by date. I've tried putting the date order by parameter at the end but no matter what, the other orderbys get ignored, seemingly.

Comment: So even sorting by the named clauses is failing?  Happy to review your latest if you want to update your Q.  You may need to use WP_Query to pull posts and then do some manual iteration through the array for sorting.  In cases like this, or more often, when grouping posts, for past projects, this was typically what I resorted to.

Comment: @jdm2112 Sorry for the delay. There are thousands of possible posts, I'm worried about the overhead needed to parse all that.